# How to handle non-string config with Hydra?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Consider the following example:

```py
from loguru import logger
import sys


logger.add(sys.stdout, level="INFO")
```

It is pretty simple to create a hydra config for the level parameter:

```yaml
log:
  level: INFO
```

On the other hand, I don't know how to create a config parameter for `sys.stdout`? I tried to do something like:

```yaml
log:
  level: INFO
  stream: sys.stdout
```

However, in the script:

```py
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../config", config_name="main")
set_log(cfg: DictConfig):
  logger.add(cfg.log.stream, level=cfg.log.level)
```

`cfg.log.stream` gives the string `"sys.stdout"`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use OmegaConf [custom resolvers](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/custom_resolvers.html#custom-resolvers) for a case like this.

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
import sys

OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("sys.stdout", lambda _: sys.stdout)

c = """
  log:
    level: INFO
    stream: ${sys.stdout:_}
"""

cfg = OmegaConf.create(c)
print(cfg.log.stream)
```

Outputs:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but the shortest one is the resort to `eval()`

```py
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../config", config_name="main")
set_log(cfg: DictConfig):
  logger.add(eval(cfg.log.stream), level=cfg.log.level)
```